# Looking for the Blender.exe file to switch .blend default app but cant find it

Tags: file-browser

I downloaded update but my .blend files keep opening with old version of Blender. I'm trying to change "open with" on individual files but i cant find the actual Blender.exe file location in the 2.82 file. Silly but I can't.

Comment: Hello :). Windows? *Program Files > Blender Foundation > Blender 2.82 > blender.exe*

Comment: Still cant find it. I have Blender stored in my D drive for reference. The file that showed up was titled simply "2.28" with trees being "datafiles," "python" and "scripts." Would it be in there of is it some external entity? Also I cant find "Blender Foundation" anywhere.